# How to subtract 7 days from a given date?

Tags: python, datetime

How can I subtract 7 days from my entered date, April 22? I expected to get April 15.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date = str(input('Enter ATP date(Format Mmmmm Dd): '))
prev_date = date - timedelta(days=7)
```

error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Comment: You have to convert the input string into a datetime first.

Comment: You can use `datetime.strptime` with `'%B %d'` to parse your `str` into a `datetime`, then the rest should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date = str(input('Enter ATP date(Format Mmmmm Dd): '))
date = datetime.strptime(date, "%B %d")
prev_date = (date - timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%B %d')
```

Comment: Hi David, the 2nd date variable is printing `1900-04-22 00:00:00` , expecting "April 22"

Comment: in that case after prev_date has been calculated you can reformat date to the required format using date = date.strftime('%B %d')